# Why does FETCH FIRST N ROWS not work in combination with WITH statement?

Tags: sql, db2, fetch, db2-zos

I have the following SQL statement which does not run on my DB2 database:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT * FROM sysibm.systables
)
SELECT a.* FROM a
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS
```

Without the **FETCH** statement it works. The error message I get is:

> Illegal use of keyword OPTIMIZE, token ERR_STMT
>   WNG_STMT GET SQL SAVEPOINT HOLD FREE
>   ASSOCIATE was expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I just forgot to copy the `ONLY` keyword. If I add it the query still does not work! Same error message.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the `ONLY` keyword at the end of the FETCH clause.

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT * FROM sysibm.systables
)
SELECT a.* FROM a
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I only forgot to copy the `ONLY` here. I used it in the original statement and the query did not work. I have the feeling it is connected to the `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the Only Keyword at the end. Example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause).

Answer (score 0):

While the example you give is likely simplified, how about putting the fetch first clause in the first select portion?

I can never read the documentation clearly, but as the with-statement creates a common-table-expression, you might not be able to use the fetch-first-clause on selecting from it. According to [this documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc/rbafzmst295.htm), having the fetch-first-clause in the select of the with-statement is valid syntax.

i.e.

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT * FROM sysibm.systables
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT a.* FROM a;
```